# How to remove Chrome Android badge on PWA icon

Tags: google-chrome, icons, progressive-web-apps

I'm creating a PWA, and I testing on my phon ( Android ), but when I add app to Home screen, the app appears with a little chrome icon on bottom right over the app icon
How can I remove the Chrome badge on PWA's icon?

here there is a `index.html` file part

```html
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="mobile/icon_512.png">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="./icon_512.png">
    <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="mobile/icon_512.png">
    <link rel="icon" sizes="128x128" href="mobile/icon_512.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="mobile/icon_512.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="128x128" href="mobile/icon_512.png">
```

Comment: If you see the Chrome badge, most likely your app is not a valid PWA running on a HTTPS server. If you use the Chrome Lighthouse tool, it will tell you what you need to fix to make your PWA truly installable.